# Ionic Android Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.1

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle

I run the command: "$ionic cordova build android"
but I will get this error. Do you know how resolve this error?

```
Preparing Firebase on Android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/henriaycard/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Users/henriaycard/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/henriaycard/git/ionic/upsudEvenement/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle' line: 41

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> 
Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']

   > 
Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/henriaycard/git/ionic/upsudEvenement/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.6-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace
 option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
 or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:35261) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /Users/henriaycard/git/ionic/upsudEvenement/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/henriaycard/git/ionic/upsudEvenement/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle' line: 41

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/henriaycard/git/ionic/upsudEvenement/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.6-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:35261) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using mac, add following line in .bash_profile and do "source ~/.bash_profile"

```
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip"
```